# Nativescript application settings will not persist username and password

Tags: nativescript, application-settings

I am using https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/application-settings to persist username and password when a user is logged in. The issue is that it only works when I enter the credentials at first then if the app goes into the background and restarts it will be present. However, if shut down the app and start again with a fresh start the username and password will not persist. Here is my code to persist when using the nativescript dataform on the login-view-model.js file.

```
const {getString} = require("tns-core-modules/application-settings");

function LoginViewModel() {
  SelectedPageService.getInstance().updateSelectedPage("Featured");

  const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
  formMeta: {
        "isReadOnly": false,
        "commitMode": "Manual",
        "validationMode": "Manual",
        "propertyAnnotations": [{
            "name": "email",
            "displayName": "Email Address",
            "index": 0,
            "editor": "Email",
            "validators": [
                { "name": "NonEmpty" }
             ]
        }, {
            "name": "password",
            "displayName": "Password",
            "index": 1,
            "editor": "Password",
            "validators": [
                { "name": "NonEmpty" }
             ]
        }]
    },
  formSource: {
   "email": getString("username", ""),
   "password": getString("password", "")
  },
..........
```

this code is supposed to set the email and password source properties to the last values that were entered when the app was logged into. As stated above it does not persist if the app is started only after the values are entered and the app goes into background. I know I can use SQLite but that seems like overkill to only store a username and a password.

What am I doing wrong? It is my understanding that application settings can persist data even after the app is closed and starts afresh.

Comment: It should be persistent. Your example code is incomplete, doesn't really show when you set the string on application settings. Please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. If I back out the app, my token persist with application-settings but I kill the app then restart, no go

Comment: its an overkill but i just used sqlite instead.